# How do I add a directory of .wav files to the Kedro data catalogue?

Tags: amazon-s3, kedro

This is my first time trying to use the [Kedro](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package.

I have a list of .wav files in an s3 bucket, and I'm keen to know how I can have them available within the Kedro data catalog.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's currently a dataset format that handles `.wav` files. You'll need to build a [custom dataset](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/07_extend_kedro/03_custom_datasets.html) that uses something like [Wave](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html) - not as much work as it sounds!

This will enable you to do something like this in your catalog:

```yaml
dataset:
  type: my_custom_path.WaveDataSet
  filepath: path/to/individual/wav_file.wav # this can be a s3://url
```

and you can then access your WAV data natively within your Kedro pipeline. You can do this for each `.wav` file you have.

If you wanted to be able to access a whole folders worth of wav files, you might want to explore the notion of a "wrapper" dataset like the [PartitionedDataSet](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.io.PartitionedDataSet.html) whose [usage guide](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/05_data/02_kedro_io.html#partitioned-dataset-definition) can be found in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```py
import pandas as pd

from pathlib import Path, PurePosixPath
from kedro.io import AbstractDataSet


class WavFile(AbstractDataSet):
    '''Used to load a .wav file'''
    
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self._filepath = PurePosixPath(filepath)

    def _load(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'file': [self._filepath],
                           'data': [load_wav(self._filepath)]})     
        return df
    

    def _save(self, df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        df.to_csv(str(self._filepath))

    def _exists(self) -> bool:
        return Path(self._filepath.as_posix()).exists()

    def _describe(self):
        return dict(filepath=self._filepath)
    
    
class WavFiles(PartitionedDataSet):
    '''Replaces the PartitionedDataSet.load() method to return a DataFrame.'''

    def load(self)->pd.DataFrame:
        '''Returns dataframe'''
        dict_of_data = super().load()
        
        df = pd.concat(
            [delayed() for delayed in dict_of_data.values()]
        )
        
        return df
    
    
my_partitioned_dataset = WavFiles(
    path="path/to/folder/of/wav/files/",
    dataset=WavFile,
)
     
my_partitioned_dataset.load()
```

Comment: This broadly works, but why not just drop `PartitionedDataSet` altogether and let `WavFile.load` accept a directory (either exclusively, or you can condition on directory v/s file)?

Comment: Yes, I did that in the end + some logic to deal with the s3 connection.

Comment: Did you consider using `fsspec` like the rest of the Kedro datasets with takes care of the S3 connection automatically for you in the background (and any other remote filesystems!)?

Comment: I did not, but that's a good idea. I'll have a look.